# Ionic/Angular, Submitting an Input Field from Array of Fields

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, input

I'm a little confused by how I should go about this. I have a "feed" in my app, where each post in the feed has a comment box. Here's some sample code:

```
<ion-card class="feed" *ngFor="let post of feed">
  <ion-item no-lines class="comment-input">
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Write comment ..."></ion-input>
    <button item-right ion-button (click)="feedPostComment(post)">Comment</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Now what I'm struggling to figure out is the best way to go about `feedPostComment()` to pull the text from the input field above it. I know I could use `ngModel` and I have in many cases for forms and input systems on pages where they aren't repeating in this way, but I just can't wrap my head around how I would do it in this case.

I was thinking that I could set `post.id` to be the `id` or `name` field on the `ion-input`, and target the input field directly through the DOM, but I realize that isn't good practice.

The other thing is, the feed itself will be regularly updating with new posts. Sincerest thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngModel` with an object property to store comments added to that specific post.
here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-whhb1s) example.

```
<ion-card class="feed" *ngFor="let post of feed">
    <ion-item no-lines class="comment-input">
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="post.comment" type="text" placeholder="Write comment ..."></ion-input>
        <button item-right ion-button (click)="feedPostComment(post)">Comment</button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-card>


//controller 
feedPostComment(post) {
  console.log('post_comment => ', post.comment);
  console.log('post_id => ',post.id);
}
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are awesome Apu.